# about memory management on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-leaks

here I have a tableView in my viewController, and it's like this:

```
//.h
...
UITableView *aTable;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *aTable;
//.m
@synthesize aTable;
...
self.aTable = nil; // in viewDidUnload
[aTable release];  // in dealloc
...
```

and now, in the viewDidLoad method I have to initialize this talbe, so I did this

```
// viewDidLoad
...
self.aTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:xxxxx];
...
```

but when I analyze this, it reminds me that in the viewDidLoad,

there maybe a potential leak of memory of this "aTable",

but I guess I am about to release it in the dealloc, so why is there still a leak of memory?

it is about the "retain" property?

do I have to add an autorelease to the code where alloc and initiate this tableView?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be (in a non arc environment):

```
self.aTable = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:xxxxx] autorelease];
```

This give you an autoreleased object (retain count: 0)

```
[[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:xxxxx] autorelease];
```

This retains the table(retain count: 1) in order to persist til viewDidUnload or til Dealloc

```
self.aTable = ...
```

If you dont autorelease the table you're getting a retain count: 2 (One of the alloc-init and the other from the retain property), then on the ViewDidUnload with this line `self.aTable = nil;` you are decreasing the retaing count to 1, but then assigning nil to your ivar, so you're lossing the reference to the alive table hence leaking the tableView, then in `dealloc` you will make basically this `[nil release]` which has no effect.

Comment: That what I guessed, but if so, what is the necessity of the "retain" property? I could use assign property and no autorelease, then I manually release them in dealloc, right?

Comment: Yes you could have do that, my rule is: use properties if you're gonna expose your ivar to the world or if you're gonna make a lot of assignments inside the .m (For this I use private properties). For your case I would drop the property (for me there is no point of using properties if you're not gonna take its advantages).

Comment: Also you should know that if you want to stick with the property, in an Arc environment you can't use `assign` anymore for OBJ-C classes, you have to use `weak` or if you want to preserve IOS 4 support `unsafe_unretained`

Comment: wow, that seems much more far-reached than I have thought, anyway I guess it should be ok for me to use retain with autorelease when alloc, right? Thanks a lot for you answer!